# Code coverage for third party static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have a Java class that uses a third party library to retrieve data from an external service.  This third party library has a static method to retrieve the data.  Using Junit or Makito, how can I achieve 100% code coverage for this case?  I am unable to mock the static method and get to the multiple paths.
The class looks something like this:

```
import com.company.dataprovider;

Class DataAccess {
  public String getData(String key) {
    try {
      DataObject data = dataprovider.getData(key);
      return data.toString();
    } catch (ThirdPartyDataException ex) {
      log(ex);
      throw new DataAccessException(ex);
    }
  }
```

Comment: How does your code use this library? Can you use DI to stub the library and test your code? You don't need to test the library itself since the publisher's should have taken care of that.

Comment: Agreed, I don't need to test the publishers code.
If I inject something into the DataAccess class, what would it be?
Since it's a static method, passing in the dataprovider class doesn't help because static methods can't be mocked.

Comment: From your code sample, which is the call the the third party library?

Comment: Sorry, that could have been clearer.
Third party library is:
dataprovider.getData

Comment: If you can create a higher level type for the data provider, then you can inject different concrete instances and in the car of your test you can inject a mock. Alternatively you may be able to use something like PowerMockito to mock the static method. I would however suggest the former since it provides greater decoupling.

Comment: If I create a high level type to wrap the third party library, I still have the same problem of creating a test for the implementation that uses the third party.
(The DataAccess class in this example is basically an implementation for the higher level type)
Moving the problem to another class doesn't make it go away.

Comment: Using PowerMockito may not be an option.  The team isn't going to like introducing another unit test library.

Comment: I was thinking that by introducing a higher level type, you use a mock instance for the third party library that does what you want. As you said earlier you don't want to test that library, just your code around the call to that library.

Comment: More specifically, you allow your class to have its dependency on the third party library be injected into your class. For production you use the real class but for testing you use a stub or a mock that you create and control.

Comment: I'm confused on what you are suggestion for the higher level type.
I want to test all the lines of code in the DataAccess class.  I'm fine if the third party library is mocked out, but I can't mock it, because it is static and I can't create an interface for it because it is a static method and I couldn't make the third party library implement the interface anyway.
I tried using a java.util.function.Function interface, but I was still left with having to have an implementation that needed testing that had the third party static method in it, that couldn't be tested.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the problem seems to be that the code has a hard dependency on the third-party library. If we can remove that we should be in a better place.

To do this, first we create an interface to represent the type for the work done by your third party library. For example IDataProvider which has one method - getData(key).

Then using a composition like approach you make a concrete Data provider implementation DataProviderImpl which calls the static method:

```
Class DataProviderImpl implements IDataProvider {
    public getData(key) {
        **call the third party static method**
    } 
}
```

Next you change your class to require an instance of IDataProvider as a field and find some way to pass it in, either with a setter method or perhaps Spring wiring:

```
@autowired private IDataProvider dataProvider;
```

Now your code does not have a hard dependency on the third party library.

Finally, for testing you make a different implementation of IDataProvider such that it does what you need for the purpose of your test.

Comment: You're close to the crux of the problem.
The problem is how to test the method that calls the third party static method.
In a project that requires 100% code coverage for all developed code, merely creating an interface and having a test implementation doesn't solve the problem of testing the real implementation code.
So in your example, how does one write a unit test for the DataProviderImpl class?

Comment: You're also assuming it is a Spring app.

Comment: I would argue that you do not have to test the real implementation of the dataProvider class because it does not do anything beyond calling a third party library for which you are not responsible to test. You should just test the code that calls the Data provider. This seems like a good example why mandating 100% code coverage can be problematic, unnecessary time is spent trying to force testing things.

Comment: You do not have to use Spring, it is just one pattern for using DI. A simple setter method would do the trick too.

Comment: 100% code coverage mandate is a different topic (though, I agree; it's problematic).
Let's assume I can't change the 100% code coverage mandate and ALL code must be covered, event the DataProvider class that only exists to call the third party driver.
Is there no way, other than PowerMock (or implementing the same byte code manipulation that PowerMock does)?

Comment: There is no other way that I am aware of.